# Import Term Set with Nav URL & Custom Properties

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, stsadm, managed-navigation, term-set

How can I import a term set that is used for navigation into another site collection on a different sharepoint server?

Originally we tried moving it with the who site collection using stsadm -o export and stsadm -o import - but this failed to take any termsets with it.

we have then tried the standard CSV approach and this took across the terms, but it didn't have the navigation simple link urls, whether it appears in global/current navigation, any custom properties or the custom order - all of which are needed.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have some answer to this question? Looks like Microsoft, does not support it. -Shahzad

Comment: only way I found was to use a powershell script to export it into an xml file first and then another to import it. I never could find one good example of this though, so ended up piecing several examples together - good luck!

Comment: I found how to export the Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl into CSV with PowerShell but I don't know how to import this value. Do you happen to know?